# Azure Logic App: Checking whether property exists in a json object

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a JSON coming from an 'SQLServer GetRecords (V2)' action like the following. Unfortunately, the response will not contain fields with null values. In my example, the 'Name' field is null for some items.

```
[
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "378fd3bc-0cd4-4171-8e7d-462461086580",
    "RowID": 1,
    "Name": "1234"
  },
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "378fd3bc-0cd4-4171-8e7d-462461086580",
    "RowID": 1
  }, ...
}
```

I want to iterate these items and pass each item to another HTTP endpoint.

When I use **item()['Name']** or **item()?['Name']** to access the name field it will fail for the second item saying

**The template language expression  cannot be evaluated because property 'Name' doesn't exist, available properties are ...**

I see a lot of people using xpath function combined with xml function to retrieve the value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference

But when I use some think like **xpath(xml(item()), '/Name')**, it will throw an error saying

**The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'JSON root object has property '@odata.etag' that will be converted to an attribute. A root object cannot have any attribute properties. Consider specifying a DeserializeRootElementName. Path '['@odata.etag']'.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xml for usage details.**

### Update 1

I got this working with the following expression, I really do not like this

```
first(xpath(xml(addProperty(json('{}'), 'obj', item())), '//obj/Name[1]/text()'))
```

Is there any other easy way to fix my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: we can use contains in regular expression it will evaluate whether a key exist in JSON object or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this problem, it seems you get "**Name**" value in "**For each**" loop from the the response of "**SQLServer GetRecords (V2)**" directly. We can just use a "**Parse JSON**" action to solve this problem easily. Please refer to my logic app below:

**1.** I initialize a variable store the same json data as yours to simulate the response from "**SQLServer GetRecords (V2)**".

[image]

**2.** Then add "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the jsondata. We can click the "**Use sample payload to generate schema**" button and copy jsondata into it. It will generate the schema automatically. The schema shown like below (**please note**: **the schema specifies whether these fields are required in** `required` **property**).

```
{
    "items": {
        "properties": {
            "@@odata.etag": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "ItemInternalId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "RowID": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "@@odata.etag",
            "ItemInternalId",
            "RowID"
        ],
        "type": "object"
    },
    "type": "array"
}
```

[image]

**3.** Now use "**For each**" to loop the `body` from "**Parse JSON**" and set the "**Value**" box with `Name` property from "**Parse JSON**".

[image]

**4.** Run the logic app, it works fine without any error message.
[image]
[image]

Comment: ParseJSON is really a simpler solution to me, Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with JSON:

```
item()?['Name']
```

Comment: This works only if item() is null, this wont work if only 'Name' field is not available

Comment: @shams.kool can you add your logicApp code? "item()?['Name']" is working fine for me when "Name" is not available in json

Comment: This works when we have an input with a schema, like an HTTP request, not from the sources like SQL Server, Adding a JSON parser with a schema seems a better solution for me.

Comment: How to get value of "Name" when we use item()?['Name']

Comment: "item()?['Name']" also worked for me.  To get "Name", you don't need anything, you just pass  "item()?['Name']" and if there is anything there it gets returned, otherwise empty. 

Thanks Jason

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking to check if a JSON property exists, you can use a condition with `not` & `empty` expressions like this -

```
  "expression": {
    "not": [
      {
        "empty": [
          "@JSONobject()?['keyName']"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
...
..
.
```

Comment: How can we use this with And another condition?? like I want to check whether Name is there or not AND Name is equal not to "xyz"

Answer (score 1):

... it seems like an old but still valid question.

What you can do is actually use "configure run after". Initialise Variable type Boolean, then on the next box try to set the variable to expression "not(empty(<your property here))".
This action will fail if the property does not exists. So follow with another "Set Variable" to expression "false". And on this action configure run after to be run if previous action fails.
If next item is "Check condition" your test variable will be false if the property did not existed or was of empty value.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. You can just use the Null function in the Logic App:

[image: see screenshot]